# Having trouble randomizing choice using (Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)). When applied to variable "computerChoice", same number always results

Tags: javascript, html, button, random, generator

When the button on-page is clicked it always results in the same output, which is  1 or "Wealth will find you". I have been tinkering and tweaking for a long while and have been unable to find a solution. Any tips or suggestions would be appreciated, even just a place to start troubleshooting!

```js
let computerChoice = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 3));

function clickEvent() {
  if (computerChoice === 0) {
    alert("You will perish soon.");
  } else if (computerChoice === 1) {
    alert("Wealth will find you.");
  } else if (computerChoice === 2) {
    alert("Love is in the air.");
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="index.js"></script>
  <title>8Ball</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class=header>Cower in Fear, the Magic 8 Ball is here</h1>
  <div class="container-one">
    <img class="hero-image" src="Images/8ball.jpeg" alt="8ball">
  </div>
  <div class="container-two">
    <!--<button id="action">Swirl the 8ball</button>-->
    <input id="action" type="button" value="Swirl" onClick="clickEvent();" />

    <h3 class="button-text">Hit the swirl button to discover what the future holds!</h3>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Demo: https://seahorsesforever.github.io/8Ball/

Comment: Are you ever *changing* that variable?

Comment: Sounds like you want a different random number each time clickEvent happens.  So put the code that generates the random number inside clickEvent.

Comment: Got it to work! Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as expected. I have place the `computerChoice` variable inside the `clickEvent` function to make it generate the random numbers as expected.

```js
const
    swirl_btn = document.querySelector('#action')

function clickEvent() {

    let
        computerChoice = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 3));

    if (computerChoice === 0) {
        alert("You will perish soon.");
    } else if (computerChoice === 1) {
        alert("Wealth will find you.");
    } else if (computerChoice === 2) {
        alert("Love is in the air.");
    }

}

swirl_btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    clickEvent()
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <title>8Ball</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 class=header>Cower in Fear, the Magic 8 Ball is here</h1>
    <div class="container-one">
        <img class="hero-image" src="Images/8ball.jpeg" alt="8ball">
    </div>
    <div class="container-two">
        <!--<button id="action">Swirl the 8ball</button>-->
        <input id="action" type="button" value="Swirl" />

        <h3 class="button-text">Hit the swirl button to discover what the future holds!</h3>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```